# Dumping out Value on console using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I come from PHP background and am used to doing `var_dump`, `echo` and `print_r` while doing some kind of debugging.

I have just started on jquery, today is my first day infact and am trying to see if there is a way to dump out value to firebug console.

Do we have similar function to `var_dump` or `echo` in jQuery or any other way to get values or debug statements displayed on the console ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use Console.log()

http://getfirebug.com/logging

HTH

Comment: I am not sure if this would work as I need to see if particular function is called or not and so in that particular function am using echo or print statement and so please explain about console.log thing, do I need to put console.log into my function ?

Comment: Its exactly what you want. but instead of `echo $var;` like you'd do in PHP, in your javascript you write `console.log(var_name);`

Comment: I am doing that way only but still it is not printing the values in the console of firebug.

Answer (score 1):

To see if a particular function is being called or not, it might be more useful to set a debugger breakpoint instead.  See here:  http://getfirebug.com/javascript

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use my [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/), which has a console that works in all the major browsers and displays a list of properties for any object passed to its logging calls.

Comment: Can't I just `echo "Hello"` in my function and see if it gets printed on firebug console to see if am reaching that particular function or not ?

Comment: `window.console.log("Hello");` will work, as others have said. You do need to make sure Firebug is active at the time: press F12 or click the icon in the bottom of the window.